# How to add HTML Menu bar above the Shiny Dashboard Header

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I Have HTML menubars looks as below(with searchbar and arrow mark in menu navigation) if i run only the HTML file
[image]

when i include the HTML menubar above the Shiny Dashboard header, it is not displaying the searchbar and arrow mark in menu navigation. [image]

How to address this issue.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(NA, 1:10), V2=c(1:10, NA), V3=c(1:4, NA, 5:10))
naRows <- apply(df, 1, FUN=function(x) length(which(is.na(x)))) 
naRows <- which(naRows > 0)
naRows
```